Semistability of the $\ell$-adic representation of variety with semistable reduction
The question is in the title, but here's some quick background.
It's easy to show (assuming smooth-proper base change) that the $\ell$-adic cohomology of a variety over the fraction field of a DVR with good reduction is unramified. My question is how to prove that for a variety with semistable reduction that its $\ell$-adic cohomology is unipotent. Of course this is true after finite base change by the $\ell$-adic monodromy theorem.
The $p$-adic analogue is the famous $C_{st}$-conjecture first proved by Tsuji, but is there a simple proof along the lines of the "good reduction implies unramified $\ell$-adic cohomology" for the "$\ell$-adic $C_{st}$"?

I would do it like this:
The cohomology of the generic fiber is the cohomology of the special fiber with coefficients in the nearby cycles complex. The inertia group acts on the nearby cycles complex, and, crucially, acts trivially on a space. When a sheaf has an endomorphism, any eigenvalue of the endomorphism on the cohomology of a sheaf must be an eigenvalue of the endomorphism on the sheaf, so it suffices to show the inertia action on the nearby cycles sheaf is unipotent.
This is a purely local question, so we can pass to a local model of semistable varieties. An explicit calculation of nearby cycles finishes the job.
I think you can derive this from Grothendieck's geometric proof of the monodromy theorem in SGA - I believe it proceeds by base changing to make things semistable followed by an argument like this one.

Thank you for your answer, but it looks like I'll need to learn what this nearby cycles complex is to parse it. What is a good introduction?

@Nico It depends on your background. I don't know if it's good, but I wrote an introduction https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09693 (section 2). This has some references to the literature, though I probably should have included more.
